# Unable to restore the selection state of spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-livedata

I'm using `AppCompatSpinner` with the `ArrayAdapter`. The data of the `arrayAdapter` is coming from room db and wrapped into `livedata` in `ViewModel` class.
Everything is working fine but when i navigate to other `fragment` and come back to `Spinner` `fragment`, the selection state is gone (and it set to `selection = 0`).

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory).get(InquiryViewModel.class);

    mViewModel.getItemLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), items -> {
        dropdownItemArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        dropdownItemArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        itemType.setAdapter(dropdownItemArrayAdapter);
    });
}
```

Comment: How do you get itemType? From layout inflation or you create it by yourself?

Comment: the items are come from room db

Comment: I am asking about Spinner, how you get it?

Comment: from layout inflation

Comment: Have you found a solution?